# Unable to implement fade on scrolled?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a website I am trying to make. When I get to a certain `div` I would like for the div to appear (fade) and then disappear (fade) when I scroll past it.

```
<div id="div1">
    <p class="welcomePar3">Welcome to my website! Here you will find all information related to me. Feel free to browse around!</p>
    <div id="UWIMAGE">
        <img id="imageActual" src="img/uw.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('#div2').fadeInScroll();
$('#div2').fadeInScroll({
    minDistance: 75 * $(window).height() / 100
});
```

With no luck. What should I do?

Comment: [Documentation](https://github.com/maugelves/FadeInScroll) just says: "**When your document is ready**, apply the fadeInScroll() function to an DOM element. When the screen reachs the top of the element, it will fadeIn.". Are you sure that your code is executed on document ready?

Comment: It doesnt seem to work @kosmos? How do I check the document is ready?

Answer (score 0):

You know if the document is ready easily using jQuery, it's a well known event.
Here you have an example of how your code should look:

```
// to wrap code around the jQuery document ready event
$(document).ready(function(){ /* stuff */ });

// or (shorthand for above)
$(function(){ /* stuff */ });

// so your code could look like this
$(function(){
    $('#div2').fadeInScroll();
});
```

Take care with your ids, in your js code you use `#div2` but your html has `div1` as id.

If you go to the plugin page (https://github.com/maugelves/FadeInScroll), you can see a file called [`index.html`](https://github.com/maugelves/FadeInScroll/blob/master/index.html). There you have an example of how it is.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/